# How can i use the generator which defined in my own class by my function in the same class？

Tags: python-3.x, class, generator

****It says " AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'Factorial' ", how could i tackle it?
I want to use my generator in my function in the same class.****

```py
class a:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def Factorial(self):
        res = 1
        for i in range(1, self):
            res *= i
            yield res
    def m(self):
        s = []
        for i in self.Factorial(self):
            s.append(i)
        return s
print(a.m(100))
```

Comment: You meant to write `for i in range(1, self.n)` and `for i in self.Factorial()` and `print(a(100).m())`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version:

```py
class a:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    
    def Factorial(self):
        res = 1
        for i in range(1, self.n):
            yield res
            res *= i
    
    def m(self):
        s = []
        for i in self.Factorial():
            s.append(i)
        return s


b = a(100)
print(b.m())
```

Answer (score 0):

In a class,`self` is the first parameter of the methods. However, you do not have to pass it; it is automatically passed when using the . operator on a class instance (here `self` and `m` are instances of the class)

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def Factorial(self):
        res = 1
        for i in range(1, self.n):
            res *= i
            yield res
    def m(self):
        s = []
        for i in self.Factorial():
            s.append(i)
        return s
print(a(100).m()) # a(100) creates an instance (calls __init__ with param n=100
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with using a generator that has been defined in the class in which it is being used.

Your code has a 2 errors:

1. When you are calling `range` on `Factorial` method, you are passing `self` as range limit instead of `self.n + 1`, as factorial of a natural number n is defined as: n × (n - 1) × (n - 2) × ... × 2 × 1.
2. You are calling `self.iter` which is not valid Python syntax (as you have not defined an `iter` method to your class). You should use `for m in self.Factorial():`.

Solve those and your code should work!